# PHP - headers/config "allow origin" not working

Tags: php, api, cors

My headers are not working, I get a cors error once Im requestion a site that requires the "Authorization" header. It appears, that I can put every possible value in the Allow-Origin and it outputs the same result (I can still access all sites that dont require Authorization, even though the Allow-Origin is set to a random value like "www.zzzawhdhawd.com"). I can also make GET requests, even though I clearly only allow POST.

I have a rest API and every api file starts like this

```
<?php

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS");
    header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
```

---

My apache2.conf looks like this

```
# Allow Origin
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'
```

---

.htaccess

```
# Turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine  on
# If the request doesn't end in .php (Case insensitive) continue processing rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$ [NC]
# If the request doesn't end in a slash continue processing the rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [^/]$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Rewrite the request with a .php extension. L means this is the 'Last' rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'
```

---

Did I implement the headers correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GET method is not added to headers.
Try change like this.

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");`

If it does no work try headers like this :

```
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age' => '86400',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
        ];

        foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
            header($key . ': ' .  $value);
        }
```